# Is there a function with two different pseudo-primitives? (Motivated by FTC)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, indefinite-integrals

The first form of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (for the Riemann integral) is stated as follows (in my textbook):

**FTC:** Suppose there is a finite set $E \subset [a, b]$ and functions $f, F : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

**1.** $F$ is continuous on $[a, b]$

**2.** $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b] \setminus E$

**3.** $f$ is Riemann Integrable.

Then

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(t) \ dt = F(b)-F(a)$$

Note that nothing is said about uniqueness of such $F$. This is the motivation of my question. Let me create a definition for this question's purposes:

**Definition.** Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable. A function $F : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ will be called a **pseudo-primitive of $f$** if:

- $F$ is continuous on $[a, b]$
- There exists a finite set $E \subset [a, b]$ such that $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b] \setminus E$

Now my question is: **Is there a function $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$, Riemann integrable, that has two different pseudo-primitives (disregarding constant shifts such as $F_2 = F_1 + C$)?** (If not, how to prove it?)

Comment: Let $F$ be a pseudo-primitive of $f$. $F_C : x \mapsto F(x) + C$ is also a pseudo-primitive of $f$ for all $C \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh indeed! Thanks for pointing that out, I wanted to disregard constant addition but forgot to mention. Now fixed.

Comment: Any two pseudoprimitives of $f$ differ by a constant.

Comment: Let $F$ and $G$ be two pseudo-primitives, we want to show that $F(x) - G(x)$ is constant for any $x \in [a,b]$. Let $y$ be another element in $[a,b]$, then $F(x) - G(x) = F(y) - G(y)$ if and only if $F(x)-F(y) = G(x) - G(y)$, but the latter condition is guaranteed by their being both pseudo-primitives (and the FTC).

Comment: Maybe you simply want to ask this:  Suppose that $F$ and $G$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$ and $F'(x)=G'(x)$ for all but a set $E$ [with property X].  Is it true that $F$ and $G$ differ by a constant?  The answer is yes if Property X is [finite set].  The answer is yes if Property X is [countable set].  The answer is no if Property X is [set of measure zero].

Comment: Thanks @GiovanniDeGaetano, that answers my question. If you want to add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: And @B.S.Thomson, that is very interesting. I am interested in knowing more about that. I will first try to figure it out / research it myself, and possibly ask a new question regarding your comment later. Very interesting!

Comment: This is answered in J.J. Koliha's book "Metrics, norms and integrals". Look up the phrase "generalized primitive" in the book to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by the OP I repost my comment as an answer.

Let $F$ and $G$ be two pseudo-primitives according to the definition given in the question, clearly the fundamental theorem of calculus applies to them. We claim that the quantity $F(x) - G(x)$ is constant for any $x \in [a,b]$. To show it let $x <y$ be elements of $[a,b]$, then, by the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$F(x) - F(y) = \int_y^x f(t) \, dt = G(x) - G(y).$$

Thus $F(x) - G(x) = F(y) - G(y)$ as claimed.

Comment: True in the sense that if the FTC as stated is *already proved* then uniqueness up to an additive constant is a trivial corollary.  Better is to ask for a proof that is independent of integration theory since this should be posed in the first half of a calculus course, not the second half.  For that $H=F-G$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and has a zero derivative $H'(x)=0$  at all points excepting some finite set $E$.  By the MVT the function $H=F-G$ is constant on any subinterval $[c,d]$ for which $(c,d)\cap E=\emptyset$.  Continuity supplies the fact that it is constant, in fact, on $[a,b]$.

Comment: ... and, moreover, the proof using the MVT does not need the superfluous assumption that $F'$ ($=G'$) is Riemann integrable.  In general one never wants to prove a theorem with completely unnecessary assumptions, especially elementary theorems.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I originally commented with the first line of thought that came to my mind, but, as you point out, there are more elegant ways to do so. I think you should add this as an answer, so that the OP can accept it.

Comment: Your answer was in fact the correct one.  The OP claimed that the FTC he quoted did not say anything about uniqueness.   You pointed out that uniqueness can be deduced immediately from the statement itself.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I somehow missed the notification for this answer, only noticing it today. My apologies.